# Selection issues with Low Quality Answer edition

Tags: bug, low-quality

I sometimes come across certain low quality answers that require editing (because they are right but poorly formatted, link-only, etcetera).

However, whenever I try to edit such answers, I can't select anything in any text box, which makes the edition work really tiresome, as I have to rely on ol' keyboard commands to position the cursor and Tab'ing to reach the changes box.

Also, navigating to the question in point and editing the answer on review doesn't have any of the problems mentioned here.

I believe this to be a bug, mainly because of its nuisance and because I have faced this repeatedly. If it matters, I'm using Firefox 28.0.

Comment: Does the same thing happen with all plugins and userscripts (Greasemonkey) disabled?

Comment: Even after the last night's update (which brought the new Firefox UI), I still have the problem (which I also noticed it also affects the comment box), although I can say that it isn't every time. I'll try to disable everything and try to do a full review when the opportunity is right.

Comment: I occasionally get this in Firefox too. Reloading the page usually fixes it for me.

Comment: This happens to me as well. I use Firefox 29.0.

Comment: The main problem with this is that this issue is erratic in frequency. I do have some other performance issues on other network sites, but, then again, its frequency doesn't allow to pinpoint the main cause of the problem.